# Email::MIME can't parse message from Gmail

Tags: perl, email, imap

So I'm using PERL and Email::MIME to get an email from gmail. Here is my code:

```
use Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail;
use Email::Mime;


# Creat the object that will read the emails
$server = 'imap.gmail.com';
$imap = Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail->new($server);


# User and password
$user = 'username@gmail.com';
$password = 'passowrd';

$imap->login($user => $password);

# Select the INBOX and returns the number of messages
$numberOfMessages = $imap->select('INBOX');

# Now let's go through the messages from the top

for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfMessages; $i++)
{
        $top = $imap->top($i);
    print "top = $top\n";

    $email = Email::MIME->new( join '', @{ $imap->top($i) } );
    $body = $email->body_str;
    print "Body = $body\n";
}#end for i
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
can't get body as a string for multipart/related; boundary="----=_Part_6796768_17893472.1369009276778"; type="text/html" at /Library/Perl/5.8.8/Email/Mime.pm line 341
Email::MIME::body_str('Email::MIME=HASH(0x87afb4)') called at readPhoneEmailFeed.pl line 37
```

If I replace

```
$body = $email->body_str;
```

with

```
$body = $email->body;
```

I get the output:

```
Body =
```

(i.e. empty string)

What's going on here? is there a way for me to get the raw body of the message (->body_raw doesn't work either)? I'm okay with parsing out the body using regex

Answer (score 0):

Email::MIME is not the best documented package I have ever seen.

The body and body_str methods only work on a single mime part. Mostly that would be a simple text message. For anything more complex use the parts method to get each mime component which is itself an Email::MIME object. The body and body_str methods should work on that. An html formatted message will generally have two MIME parts: text/plain and text/html.

This isn't exactly what you want but should be enough to show you what is going on.

```
my @parts = $email->parts;
for my $part (@parts) {
print "type: ", $part->content_type, "\n";
print "body: ", $part->body, "\n";
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with gmail. IMAP::Simple would fail the same way. You don't need to use IMAP::Simple::Gmail to read gmail unless you want to use the gmail IMAP extensions. This code doesn't.

Comment: I should probably mention that my simple code example will fail on even more complex mime structures, i.e. if any mime component is nested and contains sub components.

Comment: If you don't want to use the MIME parsing, i.e. you want the complete raw output just use Email::Simple in place of Email::MIME. The body method of Email::Simple returns the entire raw message as you were expecting.

Comment: I forgot one last change. The top method only returns the headers. To get the full message replace top($i) with get($i).